# What is the grammatical role of a word like "Thus" at the beginning of a sentance

Tags: conjunctions

What is the grammatical role of a word like "Thus", "Therefore", or "So" at the start of a sentance?

I was born in the US. "Therefore" I am an American citizen.

It's not an article... it's not a preposition... is it a conjunction?

Comment: What resources have you considered to try to answer this yourself?

Answer (score 1):

*Thus* and *therefore* are adverbs.

At the onset of a sentence *So* is generally used as an adverb or conjunction.

Adverb: So many played the lottery that the odds of winning were infinitesimal.

Conjunction: I wasn't feeling well. So I decided to stay home. (A better use would be to join the two sentences into one. It is getting late so I think I should head for home.)

While we are on the subject of *so*, it may also be used as an adjective.

Adjective: Perfections insist on things being just so.

Hope this helps!